# Python into Debian package: No module named error

Tags: python, debian, package, flasgger

Following the guidelines to build Debian package from a Python files powered by Flassger.

When running a build getting an error:

> ImportError: No module named swagger_spec_validator.util

Which mean, that `test.py` doesn't see `swagger_spec_validator`.

There seem to be no Swagger related pakcages for Debian at all. Should the `swagger_spec_validator` be included somewhere in `debian/control` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If swagger is the dependency of the software you package and it is not available in Debian,  You'll need to package it before.
If swagger is a dependency for test suite only, you may consider modifying or disabling the test.py by creating a patch in d/patches for example..